# Why is this responsive theme showing in full desktop-size?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, responsive

I really can't figure out what it could be that's causing my custom responsive theme to be desktop-viewed. It looks as if it's the banner, but it's not. When I remove it completely, the page still has a gap on the right side and desktop view. It's supposed to zoom in for a mobile friendly read. I'm using wordpress which may have something to do with the issue. Main front page doesn't have this problem as it doesn't use wordpress..

[temp link removed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialize screen size in the head section of every page, or you can include same header in every page!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: Thank you!! I somehow missed that. Thank you thank you